# Pegar a largura 'width' de um texto?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Geralmente pegamos a largura `width` de uma `div` ou qualquer outra tag dentro da página.

Como se pode pegar a largura de um texto puro? Por exemplo:

```html
Um texto
```

Como eu consigo saber a largura que esse texto ocupa na página em JavaScript?

> Não é o tamanho da string, é a largura em pixels.

Comment: Basta envolver o texto em um `span` e capturar o atributo `offsetWidth` dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar a largura `width` de um texto, você pode envolvê-lo em uma tag `span`. O [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) é uma tag do tipo *inline* que não causa nenhum efeito no *layout* da página. Logo o texto ficaria assim:

```
<span>Um texto</span>
```

Agora que temos o texto dentro de uma tag, fica fácil saber a largura que ele ocupa com o código:

```js
console.log($("span").width());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Um texto</span>
```

**Com VanillaJS:**

```js
console.log(document.body.querySelector("span").offsetWidth);
```

```html
<span>Um texto</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sem estar em algum elemento, não há como.
Minha sugestão é criar um wrapper para armazenar o texto e depois remove-lo.

```
var calculateTextWidth = function(text) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = text;

    document.body.appendChild(span);
    var width = span.offsetWidth;
    span.parentNode.removeChild(span);

    return width;
}
```

Calculando em um body vazio e considerando estilos default do browser.

```
calculateTextWidth('Um texto'); // 64px
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha, eu vi que usando `clientWidth` você pode obter o tamanho do elemento onde o texto se encontra:
**[Element.clientWidth - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)**

Porém tem que definir com CSS o `position` com Fixed.

```js
var text;
var fs;
function capterWH(){
 var w = text.clientWidth+"px";
 var h = text.clientHeight+"px";
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Width: "+w+" - Height"+h;
}

function insertText(txt){
 text.innerHTML = txt;
}

function sizeTxt(o){
    if(o == "+"){fs = fs + 1;}
    if(o == "-"){fs = fs - 1;}
 text.style.fontSize = fs+"pt"
}

window.onload = function(){
   text = document.getElementById("Text");
   fs = parseInt(text.style.fontSize);
}
```

```css
#Text
{
   position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<i id="result">------------</i><br />
Insira o texto: <input type="text" onchange="insertText(this.value)" value="Um texto" /><input type="button" onclick="capterWH()" value="Tamanho em PX" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="sizeTxt('-')" value="Diminuir fonte" />
<input type="button" onclick="sizeTxt('+')" value="Aumentar fonte" /><hr />
<p id="Text" style="font-size:12pt;">Um texto</p><br />
```