# Como saber se o texto ultrapassou uma div? usando JS

Tags: javascript

```css
#btn{
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nostrum nam ex optio sequi quam atque repellat debitis eveniet excepturi ad corporis velit nesciunt qui, necessitatibus sapiente magni in autem.
  
</div>
```

Comment: ultrapassou no eixo X, no Y, ou nos dois?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como saber dimensões de texto se ele não estiver envolvido por uma tag ([inclusive já fiz uma pergunta relativa aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278549/8063)).

O que você pode fazer é envolver o texto em uma tag `span` e setar `display: inline-block` no `span` para que ele tenha dimensões, ou seja, terá as mesmas dimensões que o texto ocupa. Isso não afeta em nada na fluidez do código.

Então você captura a altura do `span` com `clientHeight`.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
var div = document.querySelector("#btn").clientHeight;
var texto = document.querySelector("#btn span").clientHeight;

var checa = div-texto; // diminuo a altura da div pelo span do texto

console.log("A div tem "+div+"px de altura");
console.log("O texto tem "+texto+"px de altura");

// se "checa" for negativo, significa que o texto ultrapassou a div
if(checa < 0){
    console.log("O texto é maior que a div");
}else{
    console.log("O texto é menor que a div");
}
```

```css
#btn{
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#btn span{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nostrum nam ex optio sequi quam atque repellat debitis eveniet excepturi ad corporis velit nesciunt qui, necessitatibus sapiente magni in autem.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que visualmente mesmo sendo trabalho, mas com *jQuery* pode-se resolver assim:

```
<script>
if ($('#div-id')[0].scrollWidth >  $('#div-id').innerWidth()) {
    window.alert('Texto excedeu as dimensões da div');
}
</script>
```

Você pode colocar a ação em `.onload`, `.onclick`, `.onReady`. Vai da sua necessidade.